# Chamisha VeTish'im Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred ninety-five?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shais was 195 years old when Kenan was born.

Shais gave birth to Enosh when he was 105. Enosh gave birth to Kenan when he was 90.